# Export file with semicolon at the end of line

Tags: export, syntax

Is there a rule that tells Mathematica to set a semicolon at the end of each line (except of the last one)?

My MWE is:

```
Export["..\\Thesis\\Hamiltonian_stark.dat",Table[j + 10 i, {i, 0, 9}, {j, 0, 9}]]
```

But I want something like

```
Export["..\\Thesis\\Hamiltonian_stark.dat",Table[j + 10 i, {i, 0, 9}, {j, 0, 9}],{EndOfLine->';/n'}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
Export["t.txt", Table[j + 10 i, {i, 0, 9}, {j, 0, 9}], 
 "List", 
 "LineSeparators" -> ";\n"]
```

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
{10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19};
{20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29};
{30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39};
{40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49};
{50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59};
{60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69};
{70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79};
{80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89};
{90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99}
```

If you should happen to want a different format, try this:

```
Export["t.txt", Table[j + 10 i, {i, 0, 9}, {j, 0, 9}], "Table", 
 "LineSeparators" -> ";\n"]
```

```
 0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9;
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19;
20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29;
30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39;
40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49;
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59;
60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69;
70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79;
80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89;
90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
```

Comment: But to use the data, I want to omit the brackets.

Comment: @strpeter you should have said ...:)